# Entity Framework – linq and null values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'd like to select TeamMembers and, if available, the related User.

```
public IEnumerable<RetailersFiveTeamMember> GetRetailersFiveTeamMembers(int retailLeaderID)
    {
        var members = this.EntityDataModel.DD_RetailersFiveTeamMember.Where(d => d.CMS_User1.UserID == retailLeaderID)
            .Select(d => new RetailersFiveTeamMember
        {
            DateCreated = d.DateCreated,
            Email = d.Email,
            User = new CMSUser() { UserEnabled = d.CMS_User.UserEnabled }
        }).ToArray();

        return members;
```

If I execute this query, I get the following error (which is expected, because the **CMS_User** can be null):

> The cast to value type `Boolean` failed because the materialized value is `null`. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Then I tried it with this piece of code:

```
User = d.CMS_User == null ? null : new CMSUser() { UserEnabled = d.CMS_User.UserEnabled }
```

Then I get this exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type `MsRetailClub.Core.Entities.RetailersFive.CMSUser`. Only primitive types (such as `Int32`, `String`, and `Guid`) are supported in this context.

Can anyone show me the right way to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems your problem is related to CMS_User1 relationship.

Comment: Why not write User = d.CMS_User?

Comment: Hey Svarog: d.CMS_User has a lot of properties that I didn't need. So if possible I'd like to select my desired properties.

Comment: Hello Svarog, I think it is not the common pattern do some sub selection in EF like the example above. So, I'm pretty sure your way is the preferred way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not that the d.CMS_User value is null (I think the exception would be something like 'Object reference etc...'), but that the `d.CMS_User.UserEnabled` is null.

This will happen if the corresponding database field is a nullable boolean. Then, you can either map it to a nullable boolean in C# (`bool?`) or use a default value for nulls.

I suggest changing the definiton of `CMSUser` to use

```
public bool? UserEnabled {get; set;}
```

but you can also do

```
...
User = new CMSUser()
{
  UserEnabled = d.CMS_User.UserEnabled ?? false;
}
...
```